# The default FirebaseApp instance must be configured before the default Authinstance can be initialized

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

I am attempting to hook up my swift UI to an auth emulator. I have created a register function that refers to Auth.auth() and have specified for it to use the emulator. The app is building successfully but when I try to enter some test data and hit sign up I received this error:

"The default FirebaseApp instance must be configured before the default Authinstance can be initialized. One way to ensure this is to call `FirebaseApp.configure()` in the App Delegate's `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` (or the `@main` struct's initializer in SwiftUI)."

at this point:
[image]

I have read online that this could be due to two firebase instances being initialized but I have terminated all instances and started 1 again. I am also using firestore and storage emulators which appear to be working fine. Below is my App class (FarmersMarketapp) and Login View (Login):

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import FirebaseAuth

struct LoginView: View{
    @State private var email = ""
    @State private var password = ""
    var body: some View{
        ZStack{
            Color.black
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30, style: .continuous)
                .foregroundStyle(.linearGradient(colors:[.purple,.black], startPoint: .topLeading,endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
            
            VStack(spacing: 20){
                Text("Welcome")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.system(size:40, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                    .offset(x: 0, y: -200)
                
                TextField("Email", text: $email)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .textFieldStyle(.plain)
                    .placeholder(when: email.isEmpty){
                        Text("Email")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .bold()
                    }
                
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width:350, height: 1)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                
                SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .textFieldStyle(.plain)
                    .placeholder(when: password.isEmpty){
                        Text("Password")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .bold()
                    }
                
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width:350, height: 1)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                
                Button{
                    register()
                }label: {
                    Text("Sign up")
                        .bold()
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 40)
                        .background(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous)
                                .fill(.white)
                        )
                }
                
                Button{
                    
                }label:{
                    Text("Login")
                        .bold()
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 40)
                        .background(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous)
                                .fill(.purple)
                        )
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 350)
            
        }.ignoresSafeArea()
    }
    func register(){
        Auth.auth().useEmulator(withHost: "127.0.0.1", port: 9099)
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password){
            result, error in
            if error != nil{
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LoginView_Previews: PreviewProvider{
    static var previews: some View{
        ContentView()
    }
}

extension View {
    func placeholder<Content: View>(
        when shouldShow: Bool,
        alignment: Alignment = .leading,
        @ViewBuilder placeholder: () -> Content) -> some View {

        ZStack(alignment: alignment) {
            placeholder().opacity(shouldShow ? 1 : 0)
            self
        }
    }
}
```

```
import Firebase
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth

class AppDelegate:NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate{
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        let settings = Firestore.firestore().settings
        #if targetEnvironment(simulator)
        settings.host = "localhost:8080"
        settings.isPersistenceEnabled = false
        settings.isSSLEnabled = false
        #endif
        Firestore.firestore().settings = settings
        return true
    }
}

@main
struct FarmersMarketApp: App {
    
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) private var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView{
                ContentView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help/information I can get. I have tried looking into this issue online and it seems to only get closed to being abandoned or the solution doesn't apply.

Comment: Apologies about the length of the code block, I wasn't sure what would be relevant to solving the issue.

Comment: Do you have the full stack trace? What might be calling `auth` before `configure()` is called?

Comment: @Chris Apologies I am only just now seeing this. I ended up resolving the issue by using the swift package manager instead of cocoapods to manage the firebase dependency. Not sure what or why that worked but have seen similar solutions online with others.